# I can't understand why my bubble sort is not showing any time taken for the second array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, big-o

My code so far is this:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.Next(1, 10000);


        int[] FortyKSet;
        FortyKSet = new int[400];

        for (int ndex = 0; ndex < FortyKSet.Length; ndex++)
        {
            FortyKSet[ndex] = r.Next(1, 80000);
        }


        int[] TenKSet;
        TenKSet = new int[100];//populates the array with 100 integers

        for (int index = 0; index < TenKSet.Length; index++)
        {
            TenKSet[index] = r.Next(1, 20000);//makes the 10,000 integers random
        }

        bubbleSort(TenKSet);
        foreach (int i in TenKSet)
        {
            Console.Write(i + "," );
        }

        bubbleSort(FortyKSet);
        foreach (int z in FortyKSet)
        {
            Console.Write(z + ",");
        }

        for (int space = 0; space < 2; space++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int first, int second)
    {
        int temp = array[first];
        array[first] = array[second];
        array[second] = temp;
    }
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
    {
        int start = 0;
        bool swapMade = true;

        while (start < array.Length - 1 && swapMade == true)
        {
            swapMade = false;
            start++;

            for (int first = 0; first < array.Length - start; first ++)
            {
                if(array[first] > array[first+1])
                {
                    swap(array, first, first + 1);
                    swapMade = true;
                }
            }

        }
        DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan time;
        time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin);

        Console.WriteLine("Time for bubblesort to complete: " + time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ffffff"));

    }
}
```

When I run the program, it gives me the two sorted arrays (as it should.) Above the TenKSet array, I get the time it took to complete the sorting (ditto.) But when I run the FortyKSet, it shows a time of 0. Why is this? Shouldn't it take show twice the time it took to complete TenKSet (I believe the big-O notation here is O(sqrt(n)) but I could be wrong.)

Comment: This is very interesting part `DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan time;
        time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin);` but this one is the most `for (int space = 0; space < 2; space++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }`.

Comment: I am surprised that you didn't get 0 for both because you are measuring the time **after** the sort :]

Comment: Have a look at the `Stopwatch` class, it's easier to use for benchmarking than `DateTime`. In particular the static StartNew method is helpful: `var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check exactly what statements you are measuring. That's the statements between your two measurements using DateTime.Now.

PS. Where you say "I could be wrong", you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure `bubbleSort` duration you should wrap the *entire method*:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
{
    // start measuring
    DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;

    int start = 0;
    bool swapMade = true;

    while (start < array.Length - 1 && swapMade == true) 
    { 
        ...
    }

    // stop measuring
    TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin);

    Console.WriteLine(
      "Time for bubblesort to complete: " + time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ffffff"));
}
```